# Dynamodb aws Invalid Argument Exception

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, guzzle

I have been stuck on this for a few days now and any help would be great.

I am trying to data from CSV files into Dynamodb with the SDK for PHP. I am reading from a CSV file and writing the records into the database using `batchwrite`to insert the records. I am inserting everything as a string. It inserts about 4000 records and then gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 
'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid 
resource type' in /home/ubuntu/aws-php-
sample/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/EntityBody.php:50
```

What does this error mean, and why am I getting this?

Is it because those set of records I am attempting to insert have some characters that are not accepted by dynamo?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is when Guzzle, the underlying HTTP library of the SDK, [tries to create a request body](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/55ac3a0eda562f9d961dcd7dc4813713397c96a0/src/Guzzle/Http/EntityBody.php#L50). At some point in your process, the request body data being fed into Guzzle is invalid (`NULL`, possibly), but it's hard to determine why without additional information.

If you can figure out at what point it is failing or with what data, then you should [open an issue on the AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) with that information and the code you are using. Make sure you also check out DynamoDB's [Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) page in their docs, which explains restrictions on data.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I reinstalled guzzle again and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got similar problem. Ive noticed that dynamo didnt play well with non-utf-8 characaters. So I had to utf-8 encode them before storing them to the sessions.

Make sure you check what you are storing if this error sometimes happens